# extracting the weight that maximize my function- R code

Tags: r

I am calculating a quantile regression for a 99 sequence tau=.01,..., .99. I am doing this process for 1000 different response(y), where y_it = w^T_i  *  r_t. where i=1,...,1000

For instance for tau=.01 I will have 1000 quantile each quantile correspond to different y

So in total I will have a matrix of 1000x99, each column correspond to a specific tau values,   my code as follows:

```
#this is to calculate y observations 
all_yts1 <- matrix(nrow = nrow(return) ,
                   ncol = 1000 )
for( i in 1:1000){
  all_yts1[,i]<-rowSums(all_wts1[i,] * return) } 

###calculate quantile matrix 

tau=seq(0.01,.99,by=.01)
quant.matrix.reg3<- matrix(nrow = np1 ,ncol = length(tau) )
for( i in 1:np1){
  quant.matrix.reg3[i,]<- rq(all_yts1[,i][-1]~ x.reg[,3], tau)$rho
  colnames(quant.matrix.reg3)<- tau
}
```

I am using rho values in the code because my next step is to allocate the row that contains the maximum quantile value from each column as follows:

```
opt.w3.alltaus=matrix(ncol = length(tau) )
for(j in 1: length(tau)){
  opt.w3.alltaus[,j]=which( quant.matrix.reg3[,j]== max(quant.matrix.reg3[,j]),arr.ind = T) 
}
```

So I am expecting to allocate a 99 row numbers. for example, for tau=.01  the row that contains the maximum value is row 577. ( this what the codes tells me )

As a final step, since y_it= w^T_i  *  r_t.  I want to extract the w values that lying in the row 577 , is there anyway to do that rather than do it manually , because extracting 99 w values will be a time consuming especially if you are doing this process for several regressors.

Any advice to improve my code will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: what is return? if it is an object, i would recommend to choose a different name

Comment: yes it just 250 observations